# Identify other buttons then submit button with PHP

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a project website.
There are multiple "company" buttons which I all give a different name which is 
a mailaddress.
There is only 1 form on the website that can be filled in, but which should be send to the mailaddress that's on the "company" button.

[image]

The "Test Company" square is a button which contains a mail-address to where the form should be send to.

[image]

The button seen above here ^ will send the form with the filled in values.
How can I make this button use the mail-address in the other button?

The code:

```
function CheckValueNaam($value, $mail){
    if ($value == "" || $value < "1") {
        echo '<td width="100%"><center>Er is iets misgegaan</center></td></tr>';
    }
    else {
        echo    '<td class="tableFieldsCenter">
                    <div class="container-box rotated">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg turned-button" id="buttonValidate" name="'.$mail.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">' . $value . '</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>';
    }
}

<!-- Main -->
        <div id="main">

            <!-- Form -->
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Contact opnemen</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="post" class="formMarijn" id="reused_form">
                                <br>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Naam:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required maxlength="50">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required maxlength="50">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phone">Telefoon:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required maxlength="50">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="location">Adres:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" required maxlength="50">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Bericht:</label>
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Uw bericht" maxlength="6000" rows="7"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" id="btnContactUs">Verstuur</button>
                            </form>
                            <div id="succes_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
                                <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
                                <h3>Error</h3>
                                Sorry there was an error sending your form.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Printing the $_POST won't give me the button value
`print_r($_POST);`

Comment: Show us your code and what you've tried.

Comment: Updated it with code. Hope you can help me now. :)